# Need help improving sql query performance

Tags: mysql

This is my simplified history table structure:

```
id | property_id | price   | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at
1  |      1      |   100   | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | NULL
2  |      1      |   300   | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | NULL
3  |      1      |   300   | 2016-04-10 02:00:00 | 2016-04-10 02:00:00 | NULL
4  |      2      |   200   | 2016-04-10 03:00:00 | 2016-04-10 03:00:00 | NULL
1  |      2      |   150   | 2016-04-10 04:00:00 | 2016-04-10 04:00:00 | NULL
```

I need:

1. i want to get the records that meet a certain criteria, particularly that the created_at field is within the last 24 hours
2. i need to get the record that immediately precedes the records in #1
3. further filter results in #1 to records whose price column has had a different value in a record's history, other than -1

So far this is my query but it's a bit slow:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `history` `t1`
 WHERE `t1`.`created_at` >= '2016-04-13 00:00:00'
   AND `t1`.`created_reason` = 'Scraped'
   AND `t1`.`price` > -1
   AND (SELECT `t2`.`price`
          FROM `history` `t2`
         WHERE `t2`.`property_id` = `t1`.`property_id`
           AND `t2`.`created_at` < `t1`.`created_at`
           AND `t2`.`price` > -1
         ORDER BY DATE(`t2`.`created_at`) DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) <> `t1`.`price`
 GROUP BY `t1`.`property_ad_id`
```

Any suggestion on how to improve performance?

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some suggestions.

Use EXPLAIN to get the query execution plan.

The correlated subquery is being executed for *every* row returned from t1. That can significantly slow performance.

The correlated subquery is doing an ORDER BY on the result of a function.That means MySQL has to evaluate that expression for every row that satisfies the predicates, and then do a sort operation. (With the LIMIT 1, MySQL may not have to completely sort the entire set, but it does need to do at least one pass to get that first row.)

Because the DATE() function is lopping off the time component, if there are multiple rows in t2 that satisfy the other predicates (earlier created_at), the same latest date with different times, it's indeterminate which of those rows will be sorted first. You could be getting a row from 04:00 rather than a row from 17:00

Suggestion: reference a bare column, and make sure an appropriate index is available.

Suggestion: get the "maximum" created at (making effective use of an index)

Suggestion: put a lower bound on how far back you are going to look in t2 for the immediately preceding row... 48 hours, 72 hours, a week?

Suggestion: make sure suitable indexes are available for both the outer query on t1 and the subquery on t2. (likely those are going to need two different indexes)

---

As a first shot at improvement, a few minor tweaks...

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM history t1
 WHERE t1.created_at >= '2016-04-13 00:00:00'
   AND t1.created_reason = 'Scraped'
   AND t1.price > -1
   AND t1.price <> 
       (
         SELECT t2.price
           FROM history t2
          WHERE t2.property_id = t1.property_id
            AND t2.created_at  < t1.created_at
            AND t2.created_at  > t1.created_at + INTERVAL -30 DAY
            AND t2.price > -1
          ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC
          LIMIT 1
       )
 GROUP BY t1.property_ad_id
```

It's likely the most suitable indexes would be

```
... ON history(created_reason,created_at,property_id,price)
... ON history(property_id,created_at,price)
```

To get the GROUP BY optimized (to avoid a sort operation) we might also consider trying an index with a leading column of `property_ad_id`. That's a long shot, but possibly worth a test, to see if EXPLAIN shows it being used...

```
... ON history(property_ad_id,created_reason,created_at,property_id,price)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I will try all your suggestion.

Comment: can you take a look of my sql fiddle i created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b903/2/0

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is collapsing the rows for a given table1_id into a single row. If you want all the rows remove the GROUP BY.  (Did you mean to use an ORDER BY clause?) The GROUP BY in the SQLFiddle is significantly(?) different than the original query. The GROUP BY is odd, but it is on a column not referenced elsewhere in the query. The question didn't say anything about returning a different result, I didn't mention it struck me as odd.  (I've been chastised for making remarks about details that aren't related to the question that was asked.)